# UI Bootstrap modal window (service) refreshes page while opening

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I am using UI bootstrap modal window to show a form which takes data from a controller and passes on to modal window. But when window pops up, the controller is getting called and all the service calls are being made again, eventually reloading the page. 
Can someone help on how to prevent this reloading? Basically activate() function is called again after the modal window is popped up.

Thanks,
-/Sammi
P.S. I am newbie to angular. Please help.

Comment: If your modal opens on button's click please make sure button has type="button"

Answer (score 0):

I actually fixed it. Now I created a new directive from Modal window and passed the controller instance to it. 
Thanks,
-/Sammi